# R: Subsetting Data on Multiple Conditions

Tags: r

I have a sample dataset that looks like this:

```
+-----+----+--------+
| Row | ID | Status |
+-----+----+--------+
|   1 |  1 |      2 |
|   2 |  1 |      2 |
|   3 |  2 |      0 |
|   4 |  2 |      1 |
|   5 |  3 |      1 |
|   6 |  3 |      1 |
|   7 |  3 |      1 |
|   8 |  4 |      0 |
|   9 |  4 |      1 |
|  10 |  4 |      2 |
+-----+----+--------+
```

I want to subset the data by each ID with a status of 0 AND (1 OR 2). The final dataset would look like this:

```
+-----+----+--------+
| Row | ID | Status |
+-----+----+--------+
|   3 |  2 |      0 |
|   4 |  2 |      1 |
|   8 |  4 |      0 |
|   9 |  4 |      1 |
|  10 |  4 |      2 |
+-----+----+--------+
```

I'm having trouble doing this for some reason, can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use a tidyverse approach.  After grouping by 'ID', `filter` where there are `all` values 0, 1 , 2in 'Status'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(c(0, 1) %in% Status)|all(c(0, 2) %in% Status))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Status
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     2      0
#2     2      1
#3     4      0
#4     4      1
#5     4      2
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(0 %in% Status & any(1:2 %in% Status))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Status
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     2      0
#2     2      1
#3     4      0
#4     4      1
#5     4      2
```

---

Or create the logical expression with `sum`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(sum(Status %in% 1:2) > 0, 0 %in% Status)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[0 %in% Status & any(1:2 %in% Status)], ID]
```

Or another option

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[all(c(0, 1) %in% Status)|all(c(0, 2) %in% Status))], ID]
```

---

Or using `base R` with `subset`

```
subset(df1, ID %in% names(which(rowSums(table(df1)> 0) >=2)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    Status = c(2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset those `ID`s where there is at least one value of `Status` as 0 and one value of `Status` as either 1 or 2. This can be written in `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(Status == 0) & any(Status %in% 1:2))

#    Row    ID Status
#  <int> <int>  <int>
#1     3     2      0
#2     4     2      1
#3     8     4      0
#4     9     4      1
#5    10     4      2
```

This can also be written in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(Status == 0) & any(Status %in% 1:2)], ID]
```

and base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Status, ID, FUN = function(x) any(x == 0) & any(x %in% 1:2)) == 1)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Row = 1:10, ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), Status = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```